# Why does DecorView become null？

Tags: android

The error log is:

```
Thread Name: 'main'
Back traces starts.
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams android.view.View.getLayoutParams()' on a null object reference
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleWindowFocusChanged(ViewRootImpl.java:3088)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.access$1100(ViewRootImpl.java:178)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:4796)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8178)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1101)
Back traces ends.
```

I have investigated the source code in `ViewRootImpl.java`:

```java
private void handleWindowFocusChanged() {
        if (hasWindowFocus) {
            mWindowAttributes.softInputMode &=
                    ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_IS_FORWARD_NAVIGATION;
            ((WindowManager.LayoutParams) mView.getLayoutParams())
                    .softInputMode &=
                    ~WindowManager.LayoutParams
                            .SOFT_INPUT_IS_FORWARD_NAVIGATION;
            mHasHadWindowFocus = true;
        } 
    }
}
```

Look at `mView.getLayoutParams()`，that `mView` object is `null` results in this error.

To my understanding, `mView` is an object of `DecorView`, however，I still don't know why `mView` becomes `null`.

Comment: [Do not post images of code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), just copy the code into the post instead.

Comment: ok, I'll fix it right now.